Bulk PDF signing in Acrobat, using a Smart Card/ PIN
I need to digitally sing a batch of pdf files using a smart card and PIN.
Is there a way of automating this in Adobe Acrobat Pro?
So far, I have tried a JavaScript code, but it works with .pfx file and password. My requirement is to use a certificate on the Smart Card and a PIN.
